# How do i skip the first Button, if it already has Content in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y3aS.png

So im trying to make a Contact List Application for my first real project ever. For now i just want the first name and the last name to be shown in the Button and i already kinda found a way how to do it. However, when the Button has Content, i want to skip it and update the next Button to whatever i type in. How do i do that? I've already tried something, but it clearly doesn't work because it just updates.

```
      private void btn_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn_contact1.Content = firstname.Text + " " + lastname.Text;

        firstname.Text = "";
        lastname.Text = "";
        phonenumber.Text = "";

        if(btn_contact1 == Content) 
        {
            btn_contact2.Content = firstname.Text + " " + lastname.Text;
        }
        else if(btn_contact2 == Content) 
        {
            btn_contact3.Content = firstname.Text + " " + lastname.Text;
        }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using .add to append to an observablecollection of person? Or personviewmodel. You could then bind that collection to itemssource of a listbox. Template each into a button or whatever you like showing the person's name.  If you're going to do any significant wpf development you should learn mvvm. If for no other reason than this is what everyone uses. If you want help then every time you ask a question the experienced devs reading your code are going to be unfamiliar with your approach if it's not mvvm.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achievie your goal is:

```
private void BtnWriteContent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string nameAndSurname = "Name Surname";

    if(BtnFirstContent.Content == null || BtnFirstContent.Content.ToString() == String.Empty)
    {
        BtnFirstContent.Content = nameAndSurname;
    }
    else
    {
        BtnSecondContent.Content = nameAndSurname;
    }
}
```